# Event triggering multiple times

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc

```
window.getProjectId = function() {
Bidding.deployed().then(function(instance) {
  instance.projectReturn({}, function(error,result) {
    if(!error)
      var pid = (result.args.projectId);
       getPro(pid); });
   })

}
```

In the above code when the **getprojectID** function is called for first time the event **projectReturn** is triggered for one time when called second time the event is also triggered for two times like this it is going  on increasing can anybody help on this. I am using truffle and testprc

Comment: This question is about programming not Ethereum. But without the source of your project is almost imposible to tell. Is projectReturn an event? In that case you can use a global to know that an event was already created.